# How to isolate one specific key on a python dictionary.

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to read some metadata from a lot of video files. After some research I bumped on http://www.scikit-video.org. and I used skvideo.io.ffprobe which gave me the result that I wanted. It  returns a dictionary with the info I'm looking for.

It looks like this:

```
{ "@index": "0", "@codec_name": "mjpeg", "@nb_frames": "2880", "disposition": {"@default": "1", "@dub": "0", "@timed_thumbnails": "0"}, "tag": [{"@key": "creation_time", "@value": "2006-11-22T23:10:06.000000Z"}, {"@key": "language", "@value": "eng"}, {"@key": "encoder", "@value": "Photo - JPEG"}]}
```

Or with a pretty printing:

```
{
    "@index": "0", 
    "@codec_name": "mjpeg", 
    "@nb_frames": "2880", 
    "disposition": {
        "@default": "1", 
        "@dub": "0", 
        "@timed_thumbnails": "0"
    }, 
    "tag": [
        {
            "@key": "creation_time", 
            "@value": "2006-11-22T23:10:06.000000Z"
        }, 
        {
            "@key": "language", 
            "@value": "eng"
        }, 
        {
            "@key": "encoder", 
            "@value": "Photo - JPEG"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is how can I isolate the date "2006-11-22T23:10:06.000000Z". I tried a few different things but I got stuck. I can't get the keys or values. I believe I'm missing something.

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by ``` isolate the date```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any assumption that the first element of tag list contains creation time, you may find out **where** creation_time is specified...

```
data = {"@index": "0", "@codec_name": "mjpeg", "@nb_frames": "2880", "disposition": {"@default": "1", "@dub": "0", "@timed_thumbnails": "0"},
        "tag": [{"@key": "creation_time", "@value": "2006-11-22T23:10:06.000000Z"}, {"@key": "language", "@value": "eng"}, {"@key": "encoder", "@value": "Photo - JPEG"}]}

def get_creation_time(data):
    for inner_dict in data["tag"]:
        if inner_dict['@key'] == 'creation_time':
            return inner_dict['@value']
    raise ValueError('creation_time key value is not in tag information')
```

This also assumes that every "inner dict" in tag contains @key and @value.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list as the value to the key `"tag"`, so to access it you'll need to get the list out of the dictionary as so.

```
your_dict = #The code you're using to get that dictionary
internal_list = your_dict["tag"]
correct_dict = internal_list[0] #Because it's at the first position of the list
print(correct_dict["@value"]) #This prints the value of that dictionary from within the list at value of key "tag"
```

Or you can do it all in one step

```
your_dict = #The code you're using to get that dictionary
print(your_dict["tag"][0]["@value"])
```